# If nested inside if statement - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is it possible to nest an `if` statement inside another `if` statement? I find this strange, as I have never seen it used this way. If it is, could you please point to any available documentation?

```
if (room === 'ballroom') { 
  weapon = 'poison';        
  if (suspect === "Mr. Kalehoff") {
    solved = true; // correspond to 
  }
```

Comment: Yes. "12 more to go..."

Comment: There's probably no specific documentation about nested `if`s. It's just a generic flow control structure.

Comment: You may nest them as deeply as necessary, as long as you have the correct number of opening and closing `{ }` pairs

Comment: I can't think of a language off the top of my head where one can't nest conditionals

Comment: I edited the question to show that you don't have a closing brace on the outer if condition.

Comment: [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) ...

Comment: You should probably stick with either double quotes or single quotes. Try not to mix them up.

Comment: When you ask "Is it possible", why not just try it and see if it works?

Comment: I have tried, I just wasn't sure what the 'best practice' for nested `if` . Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to nest an if statement inside another if statement?

Yes.

> If it is, could you please point to any available documentation?

[ECMAScript says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-if-statement):

> ```
> if ( Expression[In, ?Yield] ) Statement[?Yield, ?Return]
> ```

It doesn't impose any limits on what kind of statement you can follow it with. So blocks containing other `if` statements are fine.